# Solve inequality $\sinh (2x) - 3 \sinh x \ > 0$

Tags: functions, inequality, hyperbolic-functions

> Solve inequality $\sinh (2x) - 3 \sinh x \ > 0$

Using hyperbolic trigo indenties:

$ 2 \sinh x \cosh x - 3 \sinh x \ > 0$

$\sinh x (2 \cosh x -3) \ > 0$

To solve this, we need to take

1. $\sinh x (2 \cosh x -3) \ > 0$
2. $\sinh x (2 \cosh x -3) \ < 0$

why is this the case ? I thought we are only solving for the inequality of $ > 0$

Comment: $XY>0$ can be true un two cases: 1) $X>0$, $Y>0$ or 2) $X<0$, $Y<0$ so why are you claiming that we need to consider $\sinh x (2 \cosh x -3) \ < 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that in general

> $$AB>0 \iff (A>0 \land B>0) \lor (A<0 \land B<0)$$

therefore to solve the given inequality

$$\sinh x (2 \cosh x -3) \ > 0$$

we need to solve separately two cases

- $\sinh x>0 \land 2 \cosh x -3  > 0$

or

- $\sinh x<0 \land 2 \cosh x -3  < 0$

and by the union of the solution for each case we can find the complete solution.

Comment: when are the cases when I need to solve the 2 separate cases? Because I asked a question before which is to solve $\sinh (3x-x^2) > 0$, there is only 1 case of $x(3-x)>0$ and I do not need to consider $x(3-x)<0$ whereas for this, I need to consider 2 cases

Comment: In the other problem we also need to consider two cases but for the second one we have no solution i.e. the system on inequalities $x<0$ and $3-x<0$ has not a solution and therefore the solution comes out only from the system $x>0$ and $3-x>0$.

Comment: For this kind of inequality $AB>0$ we always need to proceed by two cases, that is $$AB>0 \iff (A>0 \land B>0) \lor (A<0 \land B<0)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sinh x = \frac {e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$
$\sinh 2x - 3\sinh x = \frac {e^{2x} - 3e^{x} + 3e^{-x} - e^{-2x}}{2}$
Let $u = e^x$
$\frac {u^2 - 3u + u^{-1} + u{-2}}{2}$
Multiply numerator and denominator by $u^2$
$\frac {u^4 - 3u^3 + 3u - 1}{2u^2}$
Factor the numerator
$\frac {(u-1)(u+1)(u - \frac {3 - \sqrt {5}}{2})(u - \frac {3 + \sqrt {5}}{2})}{2u^2}$

$e^x > 0$ for all $x$ so $u> 0$ for all $x$

This gives us the intervals to consider $(0,\frac {3-\sqrt {5}}{2}),(\frac {3-\sqrt {5}}{2},1),(1,\frac {3+\sqrt {5}}{2},1),(\frac {3+\sqrt {5}}{2},\infty)$

The LHS is greater than $0$ when $u\in (\frac {3-\sqrt {5}}{2},1)\cup(\frac {3+\sqrt {5}}{2},\infty)$

or $x\in (\ln(\frac {3-\sqrt {5}}{2}),0)\cup(\ln(\frac {3+\sqrt {5}}{2}),\infty)$

Okay, for the work you have done....

$\sinh x(\cosh x - 3) > 0$

either $\sinh x > 0$ and $\cosh x > 3$
or $\sinh x < 0$ and $\cosh x < 3$

Comment: Nice solution even if I don't think that the main doubt of the asker is about the detailed solution but firstly on how to set the proper system in general.